Error in Swift SQLite Code: "Missing argument label 'value:' in call" and "Generic parameter 'V' could not be inferred"
I'm working on a Swift project where I need to store a deviceId in a local SQLite database. However, I'm encountering two errors when running the code.
The errors are:

Missing argument label 'value:' in call
Generic parameter 'V' could not be inferred

Here is my code:
import Foundation
import SQLite

class DeviceManager {
    static let shared = DeviceManager()
    private var db: Connection!
    
    private let settings = Table("settings")
    private let id = Expression<Int64>("id") // Error occurs here
    private let deviceId = Expression<String>("deviceId") // Error occurs here
    
    private init() {
        connectDatabase()
        createTableIfNeeded()
    }
    
    private func connectDatabase() {
        do {
            let documentDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
            let fileUrl = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("deviceManager").appendingPathExtension("sqlite3")
            db = try Connection(fileUrl.path)
            print("Successfully connected to the database.")
        } catch {
            print("Failed to connect to the database: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    private func createTableIfNeeded() {
        do {
            let createTable = settings.create(ifNotExists: true) { table in
                table.column(id, primaryKey: .autoincrement) // Error occurs here
                table.column(deviceId, unique: true)  
            }
            try db.run(createTable)
            print("Table created successfully.")
        } catch {
            print("Failed to create table: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func saveDeviceId(_ newDeviceId: String) {
        let insert = settings.insert(self.deviceId <- newDeviceId) 
        do {
            try db.run(insert)
            print("Device ID saved successfully.")
        } catch {
            print("Failed to save Device ID: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func getDeviceId() -> String? {
        do {
            if let row = try db.pluck(settings) {
                return row[deviceId]
            }
        } catch {
            print("Failed to retrieve Device ID: \(error)")
        }
        return nil
    }
}

First
On the line table.column(id, primaryKey: .autoincrement) in the createTableIfNeeded function, I get the error: "Generic parameter 'V' could not be inferred".
Second
On the line :
private let id = Expression<Int64>("id")
private let deviceId = Expression<String>("deviceId")

I get the error: Missing argument label 'value:' in call
I'm using swift-driver version: 1.115 Apple Swift version 6.0 (swiftlang-6.0.0.9.10 clang-1600.0.26.2)
Questions:

Why am I getting these errors, and how can I fix them?
Am I missing something in the way I'm defining the column for
deviceId in the SQLite table?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

If I understood, it might be due to the fact that Expression is a new object in Swift 6, so you need to write something like SQLite.Expression or Swift.Expression (in the other case) to specify which Expression you want to use.

@Larme Yes, you're right!!  it works! Thankyou!!

@Larme Please write up your comment as an answer.
